# Apache kaffka запуск тестового consumer приводит к ошибке "Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Запускаю Apache kaffka на компьютере с Win7 с помощью стандартных команд (указанных в QuickStart)

```
Zookeeper START.
E:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat E:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties

Kafka START.
E:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat E:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\config\server.properties

Create topic with one partition
E:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test

Produser START.
E:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test

Consumer START.
E:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Команды "Zookeeper START", "Kafka START", "Create topic with one partition" проходят успешно.
Последние строки лога при запуске kaffka

```
[2018-08-15 14:05:36,597] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=0] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2018-08-15 14:05:36,597] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 0]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2018-08-15 14:05:36,597] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=0] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2018-08-15 14:05:36,628] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
[2018-08-15 14:05:36,644] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Started processors for 1 acceptors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2018-08-15 14:05:36,644] INFO Kafka version : 2.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2018-08-15 14:05:36,644] INFO Kafka commitId : 3402a8361b734732 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2018-08-15 14:05:36,644] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Если сразу запустить Consumer START, то kaffka выдает много одинаковых ошибок

```
[2018-08-15 14:02:37,488] ERROR Error while creating log for __consumer_offsets-30 in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:939)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:68)
        at kafka.log.TimeIndex.<init>(TimeIndex.scala:54)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment$.open(LogSegment.scala:635)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:503)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:237)
        at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:1981)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:683)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:651)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.getOrCreateLog(LogManager.scala:651)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1.apply(Partition.scala:177)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1.apply(Partition.scala:173)
        at kafka.utils.Pool$$anon$2.apply(Pool.scala:61)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
        at kafka.utils.Pool.getAndMaybePut(Pool.scala:60)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.getOrCreateReplica(Partition.scala:172)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$9.apply(Partition.scala:286)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$9.apply(Partition.scala:286)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$7.apply(Partition.scala:286)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$7.apply(Partition.scala:280)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:259)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:280)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:1158)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:1156)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:1156)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:1076)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:185)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:110)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:936)
        ... 44 more
```

и появляется много файлов в C:\tmp\kafka-logs

[image: C:\tmp\kafka-logs]

Через некоторое время kafka останавливается и выводит

```
[2018-08-15 15:01:57,411] INFO Stopping serving logs in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2018-08-15 15:01:57,411] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in C:\tmp\kafka-logs have failed (kafka.log.LogManager
```

Если повторно запустить Kafka START, то ошибка выдается сразу, пока не почищу папку C:\tmp\kafka-logs

Мне кажется ошибка с неправильными настройками виртуальной машины JAVA (Не хватает памяти).
Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Может быть, реально памяти не хватает на целевой машине?

Comment: Да нет 4гб свободно памяти точно (всего 8Гб)

Comment: Запускаю на ноутбуке там Win7 + 8Гб, все работает с пол пинка

Comment: Пищу на .NET и C++, c JAVA дела не имел настраивать не умею, просто поставил пакеты и все

Comment: А место на диске свободного сколько?)

Comment: 96Гб свободно (SSD)

Comment: Папка Kafka на диске E, логи создаются на диске C. Но и там и там много места.

Comment: Привет, коллеги :) 
На Win 10 Pro второй или третий раз та же ошибка :(
Доступно  6Гб памяти из 16Гб.
Свободно 54Гб диска (SSD). 
kafka_2.12-2.3.0 
Вот загадка! 
Пока вижу только 2 совпадения с описанным случаем: Windows и SSD. 
В коде Java <kafka.version>2.0.1</kafka.version>  Может, это расхождение версий существенно?

Comment: Вопрос очень важный и уже почти год без ответа!.. 
Как - то удалось понять причину или решить эту проблему?